# Uncertainty principle density argument

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I proved the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle for $f$ in the Schwartz space $ S(\mathbf R)$:

$$
\int_{\mathbf R} |\xi \hat{f}(\xi)|^2 \int_{\mathbf R} |xf(x)|^2 dx \geq \frac{1}{(4\pi)^2} |f|_{L^2(\mathbf R)}^4.
$$

Now I am having a lot of trouble extending it for $f\in L^2(\mathbf R)$. Of course we have to use density of $S(\mathbf R)$ in $L^2(\mathbf R)$ and use that $xf(x)$, $\xi\hat{f}(\xi) \in L^2(\mathbf R)$ (otherwise the inequality is trivial). But I can't think of a way of approximating everything at the same time.

Any hints or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: An approximation argument is given in the book by Dym and McKean Fourier series and integrals pages 119-121. However, the authors have to go through the proof for $S(R)$ to show that it works in the $L^2$ case. I would like to see (1) if a direct proof exists *assuming* that the result holds at the level of $S(R)$. (2) If a density argument can prove the uncertainty principle over other, say, $L^p$ spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Let's just take $f_n=\varphi_n *f$, with $\varphi_n(x)=n\varphi(nx)$, and $\varphi\in C_0^{\infty}$, $\int\varphi =1$. We're assuming that $f,xf,\xi\widehat{f}\in L^2$.

Then $\int_{-L}^L |f_n-f|^2\to 0$ by a standard approximation argument, and if we choose $L>0$ large enough, then both $\int_{|x|>L}x^2|f|^2$ and $\int_{|x|>L}x^2|f_n|^2$ are small. So $\|xf_n-xf\|\to 0$.

Similarly, $\xi\widehat{f}=c\widehat{f'}$, and $f'_n=\varphi_n *f'\to f'$ in $L^2$; alternatively, $\xi \widehat{f_n}-\xi\widehat{f}=\xi\widehat{f}(\widehat{\varphi}(\xi/n)-1)$ goes to $0$ in $L^2$ norm by dominated convergence.

(Essentially, what we do here is make use of the fact that smooth functions are dense in Sobolev spaces.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Christian. Some questions: (1) are you assuming $f$ is in $L^2$? I guess the answer is yes, but then in the last paragraph I see $f'$. If $f$ is a general $L^2$ function, how do you make sense of its derivative? (2) your proof seems to work for any $L^p$ space; is that correct?

Comment: Yes, $f\in L^2$. I define $f'\in\mathcal S'$ as a distribution originally, but then $\xi\widehat{f}\in L^2$ implies that $f'\in L^2$ (use the alternative argument perhaps if you don't like this part).